# Almost impossible to see "This room is frozen" in Area 51 chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, area-51, frozen-rooms

In a chat room in Area 51 that has been frozen, such as [StackOverflow en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6493/stackoverflow-en-espanol), there is a little problem with the message that the room has been frozen by inactivity:

[image]

Believe it or not, the message is there. You will need very good eyes to see it, and it just looks like a blank spot, and people will wonder what is happening. The only way for a mere mortal to see it is to select it:

[image]

Can the color of this text be changed, so we can see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed and will be deployed in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be fixed by just changing the text color to `#E0E0E0`:

[image]

Much better.

Comment: +1, but I'll accept a moderator's answer if it comes with a [tag:status-completed].

Comment: Why did you feel this warranted an answer? They could change it to *any* lighter color that would show up on the blue,which is what the question asked for. I don't see how this contributes anything.